# How does Sauron get away after the War of Wrath

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, sauron

In the *Silmarillion* is says that Sauron speaks to Eonwë after the war of wrath, so I assume Sauron is in captivity? Does it mention in any of the histories how he manages to escape?

Given everything that follows it appears to be quite an oversight.

Comment: IIRC, Sauron claimed to have repented and seen the error of following Morgoth, and the Valar let him go. (Which would make them responsible for all the havoc Sauron caused later, but being a Vala means never having to say you're sorry.)

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. :)

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit The Valar did not. Eönwë was a Maia and he let him go under command of returning to the Valar for judgement

Comment: @ATB That is correct, but I think the Valar must take the responsibility nevertheless.

Comment: The Valar didn't let him go,where does it say that?And why must they take responsibility?

Answer (score 2):

He fled and hid.

The leader of the victorious hosts of the West, Eönwë commanded him to return to Aman for judgement.

> But it was not within the power of Eönwë to pardon those of his own order, and he commanded Sauron to return to Aman and there receive the judgement of Manwë.
>
> <sup>The Silmarillion | Of The Rings of Power and the Third Age</sup>

Why he was not taken in chains is not said.

Sauron was unwilling to do a long period of repentance and servitude for his crimes so he "hid"

> Then Sauron was ashamed, and he was unwilling to return in humiliation and to receive from the Valar a sentence, it might be, of long servitude in proof of his good faith; for under Morgoth his power had been great. Therefore when Eönwë departed he hid himself in Middle-earth; and he fell back into evil, for the bonds that Morgoth had laid upon him were very strong.
>
> <sup>The Silmarillion | Of The Rings of Power and the Third Age</sup>

At this time Sauron was able to fully change his shape and even remain unseen if needed, and it seems the Valar had no desire to hunt for him in middle-earth.

Comment: So we don't have anything other than what's in the Silmarillion? If not I'll put it down to Eönwë being over-trustful and not chaining him when he had the chance.

Comment: @Declanr43 I've not read anything. Others may know more when they come online

Comment: @Declanr43 it's not clear that Eonwe had the ability to "chain" Sauron, who after all had no particular physical form. Even the mightiest of the Valar had to work to chain Melkor.

Comment: @MattGutting given Eönwë is described as the "mightiest" of all the Warriors of Arda, I'd expect him to be able to subdue Sauron. The wording indicates he wouldn't rather than couldn't.

Comment: Point taken. Maybe he felt that his primary focus was on Melkor, and given that he didn't have "power" to pardon Sauron, perhaps he didn't have "power" to chain him up either.